# Gstreamer client server audio streaming

Tags: c, audio, streaming, gstreamer

I want to create a simple client-server application using Gstreamer in C. The client must capture audio from microphone (1 channel, 16Khz) and send the audio stream to a server that save it as a .wav file on disk.

The actual code creates the file on disk, but it's empty. I think the server works ok, because it creates the file if I use this command as a client: gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=audio.wav ! tcpclientsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000

I need a hint about what is wrong on the client side.

Thanks!

Here is my client code: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7umVbxKsF0GVWZ3b3J3QTN2T1k

Here is my server code: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7umVbxKsF0GRDVKQXVKVXVGVnM

Answer (score 0):

Your client code is equal to below gst-launch command
`gst-launch-1.0 pulsesrc ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! audio/x-raw, format=S16LE, channels=1, rate=16000, layout=interleaved ! tcpclientsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000`

It sends a raw audio, not a wav file like your runable example.

To allow server works with this raw audio stream, remove `decodebin` put a capsfilter there to tell server the format/channels/rate ... of audio stream.

P/s: `while(1)` in your client code is bad, should remove it